# Am I able to implement Popover on each date button for ShadcnUI Calendar component?

Tags: radix-ui

I'm currently using ShadcnUI's calendar component, and what I want to do is to be able to use ShadcnUI's popover component on each date. From my understanding, each date cell of the calendar's component is basically a `<Button />`, so I'm guessing it's something like:

```js
<Button>{date}</Button>
```

But what I want to do is basically something like:

```js
<Popover>
  <PopoverTrigger>
    <Button>{date}</Button>
  </PopoverTrigger>
  <PopoverContent>Events here!!!</PopoverContent>
</Popover>
```

Is this possible?